# Can I stop Entity Framework Core from populating my result with partial data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

On [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) of the Entity Framework Core documentation, it says when querying loaded data:

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.

This is true whether it is **Eager** or **Explicit**.

I find this to be frustrating, because it will return *partial* data, which makes it seem like a complete list because there's nothing indicating that it is partial.

**Example:**

Say I have the following two classes:

```
class User {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

class Message {
    int Id { get; set; }
    List<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

And I query using the following code:

```
_dbContext.Users
    .Include(u => u.Messages)
    .Single(u => u.Id == 1);
```

My output is the following:

```
"user" {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Alice",
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Alice",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect that unless I also added `.ThenInclude(m => m.Users)`, it would give me a null or empty list, not a partial list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent EF7 from eagerly fixing up navigation properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438600/how-can-i-prevent-ef7-from-eagerly-fixing-up-navigation-properties)

Comment: @Romoku I don't really know how this would be a duplicate of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your example that Alice's message with id 1 is linked to more that one user (herself).

**I am not sure it is necessary to change this behavior**. As you mentioned, we should use `.ThenInclude(m => m.Users)` if we need the navigation property to be fully initialized.

> I would expect that unless I also added .ThenInclude(m => m.Users), it
>   would give me a null or empty list, not a partial list.

**The partial result will be a good thing when lazy loading will be implemented**. If the navigation property you will want to access is already loaded, then you will save a round trip to the database.