# EF Core returns null relations until direct access

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have some models like those below:

```
public class Mutant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Relations
    public long OriginalCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual OriginalCode OriginalCode { get; set; }
    public int DifficultyLevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual DifficultyLevel DifficultyLevel { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class OriginalCode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Relations
    public virtual List<Mutant> Mutants { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OriginalCodeInputParameter> OriginalCodeInputParameters { get; set; }
}
```

and in the `OnModelCreating` of `DBContext` I made the relations like these:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Mutant>()
            .HasOne(m => m.OriginalCode)
            .WithMany(oc => oc.Mutants)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.OriginalCodeId)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Mutant>()
            .HasOne(m => m.DifficultyLevel)
            .WithMany(dl => dl.Mutants)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.DifficultyLevelId)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

now when I request for Mutants, the OriginalCode is null:

[image: Null OriginalCode]

but as soon as I request for `OriginalCode`s like below:

[image: OriginalCodes]

then the `OriginalCode` field of the mutants will be not null:

[image: Filled Object]

What is the reason and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The reason is explained in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the EF Core documentation.

The first behavior is because EF Core currently does not support lazy loading, so normally you'll get `null` for navigation properties until you specifically load them via eager or explicit loading. However, the **Eager loading** section contains the following:

> **Tip**
> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.

which explains why the navigation property is not null in the second case.

Now, I'm not sure which of the two behaviors do you want to fix, so will try to address both.

The first behavior can be "fixed" by using one of the currently available methods for loading related data, for instance eager loading:

```
var mutants = db.Mutants.Include(m => m.OriginalCode).ToList();
```

The second behavior is "by design" and cannot be controlled. If you want to avoid it, make sure to use fresh new `DbContext` instance just for executing a single query to retrieve the data needed, or use [no tracking query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries).

**Update:** Starting with v2.1, EF Core supports [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading). However it's not enabled by default, so in order to utilize it one should mark all navigation properties `virtual`, install [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/) and enable it via `UseLazyLoadingProxies` call, or utilize [Lazy-loading without proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading-without-proxies) - both explained with examples in the EF Core documentation.

Comment: As you could guess I want to control the first behavior. But there is still a big question. This way you mentioned, I should explicitly address the relations to be filled, true?

Comment: Indeed. You have to specify each one you want to be "included" using several `Include` / `ThenInclude` methods. AFAIK there are some plans for making this automatically in the future, but for now that's the only option.

Comment: What about guessing, one never knows - for instance see a few question before yours in EF Core tag - [Can I stop Entity Framework Core from populating my result with partial data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310340/can-i-stop-entity-framework-core-from-populating-my-result-with-partial-data) :)

Comment: Now EF Core support lazy loading: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: @Pejman.Nik It's still [In Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1) though. And even when officially available, it won't be enabled by default, so `virtual` won't be enough.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are right. From Roadmap: "final release in the first half of 2018". You can enable it by `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`

Comment: Although I think not being set as default, means that it is not the recommended solution! I think if use correctly, non-lazy methods are harder to write but better for run-time, which will put many future database requests in one.

Answer (score 3):

Using Package Manager Console install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

`install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`

And then in your Context class add `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`:

```
namespace SomeAPI.EFModels
{
    public partial class SomeContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder
                    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }

        }
    }
}
```