# Entity Framework Core one to many bidirectional

Tags: asp.net-core, one-to-many, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Coming from the world of mighty nHibernate trying to get bidirectional relation to work in Entity Framework Core.

Here are my simplified entities:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class Login
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("users")
            .HasMany(x=>x.Logins)
            .WithOne(x=>x.User)
            .HasForeignKey(x=>x.user_id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Login>()
            .ToTable("logins")
            .HasOne(d=>d.User)
            .WithMany(d=>d.Logins)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.user_id);
    }
```

When I query **User**, **Logins** collection is fetched correctly. However when I query **Login** the **User** comes null.

```
 var login = DBContext.Logins.Where(x => x.email == email).SingleOrDefault();
 // login.User is null
```

Comment: You have to use `Include`, which you also must have done with User.Logins.

Comment: Put it as an answer, will mark it as answered

Comment: If it's OK with you, I'll mark it as duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42327515/861716

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core returns null relations untill direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-untill-direct-access)