# Entity Framework 6 loading child objects after other database call

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

I'm making a simple database call to load values from a table. Lazy loading is disabled and it's working as it should, meaning it doesn't populate the related tables.

For example

```
IEnumerable<FAR> fars = await ctx.FARs.ToListAsync();
```

would return a listing from this table. In this listing there is a relationship to a "Projects" table. After this query runs, "fars[n].Projects" is null, which is correct.

Now I want to grab a listing of "Projects" and only associate with the top level "Project" and none of it's children.

```
List<Project> projects = ctx.Projects.ToList();
```

As soon as I grab a listing of "Projects", "fars[n].Projects" is suddenly populated.

There was no assignment, they're 2 separate database calls. I looked at the queries running in the database. No other calls are being made.

Why is it suddenly adding these "Projects" to my original entity variable?

Comment: Proxy classes I believe, you must have `public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects` in your entity definition for `FAR`. I think using `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`in the constructor of your context should disable that.

Comment: I thought that originally. I did have    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; and   ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; I even tried assigning it to another random variable, still updates both. I'm trying to avoid selecting only the fields I need. There isn't that much data, but I do realize that it would be a fix. Just odd behavior.

Comment: The context will hook up objects automatically, so if you get a parent object with one query, then the children (or some of them) with a second query using the same context it recognises the relationship and connects the objects up.

Comment: @Mant101 Is there a way to avoid that "hook up"? Or should I crack open a new context? I feel like that could be a bit messy.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-untill-direct-access/42329028#42329028 It's for EF Core, but the same applies to EF6. No way to be avoided except with no tracking queries or separate context.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just read a SO post from EF 5. The answer is to include `AsNoTracking`. So the resulting code is `IEnumerable<FAR> fars = ctx.FARs.AsNoTracking().ToList();`

Comment: That's what I meant by **no tracking** queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to include `AsNoTracking()` in the query.

The correct code is

```
IEnumerable<FAR> fars = await ctx.FARs.ToListAsync();
```

Hopefully this helps someone else with their performance issues :)

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a performance issue because it isn't going back to the database, its just hooking up the items it already has in memory. Unless you are loading up a lot data. For big read only operations no tracking can help as the context is doing less work.

Comment: In this case there were a lot of circular references being assigned and they were running through a loop. Too much being sent through there to analyze. That was the performance hit.