# How to prevent automatic inclusion of navigation properties in unit tests

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am currently developing an app store style API which has the following entities (plus many others, but not relevant to the problem):

- App (1 to many relationship to AppRevision - contains IEnumerable property)
- AppRevision
- Installation

I have come across an odd problem where the behaviour of EF differs in unit tests to when actually running the API, in that navigation properties are automatically being included when unit testing.

Take the following code snippet from my command handler:

```
App app = await this.context.Apps
    .Include(a => a.Installations)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == command.AppId);

if (app != null) {
    // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

When running the API, if I inspect `app` after this code has been run, the AppRevisions collection on the App entity is empty, as you would expect as I have not expliclity told EF to `.Include(a => a.AppRevisions)` - the API then throws an exception when trying to process code later on that needs this data to be there.

Now look at the following unit test for the same handler:

```
[Fact]
public async void Handle_ShouldAddInstallationRecord_WhenDataIsValid()
{
    Guid testGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    CreateInstallationCommand command = new CreateInstallationCommand(testGuid, "ABC", "abc@abc.com", null);

    using (TestContext context = new TestContextFactory().CreateTestContext())
    {
        context.Apps.Add(new App() { Id = testGuid });
        context.AppRevisions.Add(new AppRevision() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), AppId = testGuid, Status = AppRevisionStatus.Approved, IsListed = true });
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        CreateInstallationCommandHandler handler = new CreateInstallationCommandHandler(context);

        CommandResult result = await handler.Handle(command, new CancellationToken());

        Assert.True(result);
        Assert.Single(context.Installations);
    }
}
```

If I step through this test, when I get to the handler and inspect the `app` variable, the AppRevisions collection has automatically been populated. As a result, the test passes because the code that requires the AppRevisions collection to be populated can execute.

The expectation is that this test should actually fail, because I'm not telling EF to include those entities in the query.

I am using a Sqlite in memory database to create the database context for my unit tests and running .NET Core 2.2

I originally thought this was something to do with the changetracker. While disabling this does solve the immediate problem reported above, it creates a load of other problems so isn't a viable solution (and probably wouldn't be the correct one anyway)

Any suggestions gratefully received

Comment: You are reusing the same context, so probably the AppRevisions are there because they are cached. Try to create another context  after the SaveChangesAsync

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access/42329028#42329028. Unfortunately they removed the part of the documentation I'm referring to. But the principle remains - when querying entities with tracking enabled, you basically have lo control over what is loaded into navigation properties. If you really want full control, then I'm afraid you should switch to DTOs/ViewModels and projection.

Comment: As always in unit tests, make sure you stay as close to the real application code as possible. The API method doesn't receive a "polluted" context. So, as said, use a new context for the part that mocks the API call. You may have to examine your other tests on this pattern.

Comment: @Alberto yes that's likely the case, but I can't create another context when I'm using an in memory database (or can I?)

Comment: @pr.lwd You create one, so you can create two, three, four....

Comment: @GertArnold yes you're right - I've figured it out. For some reason I didn't think creating multiple contexts when using an in memory data store would work. Must have had my brain in backwards. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this post in the future, the solution is as per the comments on the original question, to use separate contexts for seeding test data and getting the data later in the test:

```
[Fact]
public async void Handle_ShouldAddInstallationRecord_WhenDataIsValid()
{
    Guid testGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    CreateInstallationCommand command = new CreateInstallationCommand(testGuid, "ABC", "abc@abc.com", null);

    using (TestContextFactory contextFactory = new TestContextFactory())
    {
        using (TestContext seedContext = contextFactory.CreateTestContext())
        {
            seedContext.Apps.Add(new App() { Id = testGuid });
            seedContext.AppRevisions.Add(new AppRevision() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), AppId = testGuid, Status = AppRevisionStatus.Approved, IsListed = true });
            await seedContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        using (TestContext getContext = contextFactory.CreateTestContext())
        {
            CreateInstallationCommandHandler handler = new CreateInstallationCommandHandler(getContext);

            CommandResult result = await handler.Handle(command, new CancellationToken());

            Assert.True(result);
            Assert.Single(getContext.Installations);
        }
    }
}
```