# EF Core navigation properties not populated (again!)

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

The setup is very simple. Two tables, Endpoints and Deployments, are many-to-many and joined by a table called Services.

```cs
var query = from endpoint in db.Endpoints
    from deployment in endpoint.Service.Deployments
    select new Endpoint(
            deployment.Host,
            endpoint.Method,
            endpoint.Path,
            new Cost(endpoint.CostCredits, new PerRequest()));

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

When I run this, I get 0 results.

Inspecting `db.Endpoints[0].Service` in the debugger shows null. Coming from a slightly different angle:

```cs
var query = db.Endpoints
    .Include(endpoint => endpoint.Service)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.Deployments) // out of desperation!
    .SelectMany(endpoint => endpoint.Service.Deployments.Select(deployment =>
    new Endpoint(
        deployment.Host,
        endpoint.Method,
        endpoint.Path,
        new Cost(endpoint.CostCredits, new PerRequest()))));
```

This throws a NullReferenceException. I even tried adding this before the query:

```cs
await db.Endpoints.ToListAsync();
await db.Deployments.ToListAsync();
await db.Services.ToListAsync();
```

Same behaviour.

I've seen numerous SO questions like [EF Core returns null relations until direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42327515/1291717) but obviously they are not my case - the navigation properties are not populated even after all the data from all three tables is loaded.

How can I get the above query to work?

Here is a complete minimal repro (same as a runnable [Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8yVA9)):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace Repro
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var db = new MorpherDbContext();
            db.AddSomeData();

            var query = from endpoint in db.Endpoints
                from deployment in endpoint.Service.Deployments
                select new {
                    deployment.Host,
                    endpoint.Method,
                    endpoint.Path
                    };

            var result = await query.ToListAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
        }
    }

    public class Deployment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }

        public string Host { get; set; }
        public short? Port { get; set; }
        public string BasePath { get; set; }
    }
    public class Service
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Endpoint> Endpoints { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Deployment> Deployments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Endpoint
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; } 
        public string Method { get; set; } 
        public int CostCredits { get; set; } 
        public string CostType { get; set; } 
        public string CostTypeParameter { get; set; } 
    }

    public partial class MorpherDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("db1");
            //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ReproDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Endpoint> Endpoints { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Deployment> Deployments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:DefaultSchema", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Deployment>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Host).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
                entity.Property(e => e.BasePath).HasMaxLength(512);

                entity.HasOne(deployment => deployment.Service)
                    .WithMany(service => service.Deployments)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ServiceId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Deployments_Services");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Service>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
                entity.Property(e => e.UrlSlug).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Endpoint>(endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.Property(e => e.Path).IsRequired();
                endpoint.Property(e => e.Method).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(6);
                endpoint.Property(e => e.CostCredits).IsRequired();
                endpoint.Property(e => e.CostType).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
                endpoint.Property(e => e.CostTypeParameter).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(150);

                endpoint.HasOne(e => e.Service)
                    .WithMany(service => service.Endpoints)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ServiceId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Endpoints_Services");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

        public void AddSomeData()
        {
            var ws3 = new Service { Name = "Веб-сервис «Морфер»", UrlSlug = "ws"};

            Services.Add(ws3);
            Deployments.Add(new Deployment {Service = ws3, Host = "ws3.morpher.ru"});

            Endpoints.AddRange(new []
            {
                new Endpoint {Method = "GET", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"},
                new Endpoint {Method = "POST", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerBodyLine"},
                new Endpoint {Method = "*", Path = "russian/userdict", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"},
            });

            ws3.Endpoints = Endpoints.ToList();

            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

namespace Repro.Migrations
{
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
                name: "dbo");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Services",
                schema: "dbo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
                    UrlSlug = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Services", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Deployments",
                schema: "dbo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    ServiceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Host = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: false),
                    Port = table.Column<short>(nullable: true),
                    BasePath = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 512, nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Deployments", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Deployments_Services",
                        column: x => x.ServiceId,
                        principalSchema: "dbo",
                        principalTable: "Services",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Endpoints",
                schema: "dbo",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    ServiceId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Path = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Method = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 6, nullable: false),
                    CostCredits = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    CostType = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    CostTypeParameter = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 150, nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Endpoints", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Endpoints_Services",
                        column: x => x.ServiceId,
                        principalSchema: "dbo",
                        principalTable: "Services",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Deployments_ServiceId",
                schema: "dbo",
                table: "Deployments",
                column: "ServiceId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Endpoints_ServiceId",
                schema: "dbo",
                table: "Endpoints",
                column: "ServiceId");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Deployments",
                schema: "dbo");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Endpoints",
                schema: "dbo");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Services",
                schema: "dbo");
        }
    }
}

namespace Repro.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(MorpherDbContext))]
    partial class MorpherDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasDefaultSchema("dbo")
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.1.3")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Repro.Deployment", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("BasePath")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(512)")
                        .HasMaxLength(512);

                    b.Property<string>("Host")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)")
                        .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.Property<short?>("Port")
                        .HasColumnType("smallint");

                    b.Property<int>("ServiceId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("ServiceId");

                    b.ToTable("Deployments");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Repro.Endpoint", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<int>("CostCredits")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<string>("CostType")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")
                        .HasMaxLength(50);

                    b.Property<string>("CostTypeParameter")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(150)")
                        .HasMaxLength(150);

                    b.Property<string>("Method")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(6)")
                        .HasMaxLength(6);

                    b.Property<string>("Path")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("ServiceId")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("ServiceId");

                    b.ToTable("Endpoints");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Repro.Service", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)")
                        .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.Property<string>("UrlSlug")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(256)")
                        .HasMaxLength(256);

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Services");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Repro.Deployment", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Repro.Service", "Service")
                        .WithMany("Deployments")
                        .HasForeignKey("ServiceId")
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_Deployments_Services")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                        .IsRequired();
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Repro.Endpoint", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Repro.Service", "Service")
                        .WithMany("Endpoints")
                        .HasForeignKey("ServiceId")
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_Endpoints_Services")
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                        .IsRequired();
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a new object with `new Endpoint(...)` in your LINQ query? And do you have two classes by the name `Endpoint`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: The '''new Endpoint()''' is a different class to db.Endpoints.

Comment: Please add the repro to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: @Progman, it's 376 lines long. Are you sure you want it in the question?

Comment: Yes, the question post should contain every information needed, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374761/is-showing-a-link-to-github-source-code-acceptable. Also, keep in mind to post a "minimal" reproducible example, which shows the problem you have. If there is some code which isn't relevant it should be deleted.

Comment: @Progman - inserted the full (minimal) repro into the question.

Comment: Btw.: Your repo does not need the migration classes and the SqlServer related configurations aren't needed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
ws3.Endpoints = Endpoints.ToList();
```

This line will mess up the navigation properties/collections which are maintained by the current context of entity framework. In fact, when you try to set `Service = ws3` for the `Endpoint` objects in your `AddSomeData()` method you will get the following exception message:

> The association between entities 'Service' and 'Endpoint' with the key value '{ServiceId: 1}' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.

You are adding `Endpoint` objects via the `Add()/AddRange()` methods but without any `Service` reference assigned (or `ServiceId` value set). In combination with the line above it will break (somehow).

To fix the issue you should remove either the `ws3.Endpoints = Endpoints.ToList()` line and set the `Service` navigation properties or remove the `Add()/AddRange()` calls for the `Endpoint` objects. The `AddSomeData()` method might look like this:

```
public void AddSomeData()
{
    var ws3 = new Service { Name = "Веб-сервис «Морфер»", UrlSlug = "ws"};

    Services.Add(ws3);
    Deployments.Add(new Deployment {Service = ws3, Host = "ws3.morpher.ru"});
    var endpointsToAdd = new []
    {
        new Endpoint {Method = "GET", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"},
        new Endpoint {Method = "POST", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerBodyLine"},
        new Endpoint {Method = "*", Path = "russian/userdict", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"},
    };

    ws3.Endpoints = endpointsToAdd.ToList();

    SaveChanges();
}
```

The other solution would be:

```
public void AddSomeData()
{
    var ws3 = new Service { Name = "Веб-сервис «Морфер»", UrlSlug = "ws"};

    Services.Add(ws3);
    Deployments.Add(new Deployment {Service = ws3, Host = "ws3.morpher.ru"});
    Endpoints.Add(new Endpoint {Service = ws3, Method = "GET", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"});
    Endpoints.Add(new Endpoint {Service = ws3, Method = "POST", Path = "russian/declension", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerBodyLine"});
    Endpoints.Add(new Endpoint {Service = ws3, Method = "*", Path = "russian/userdict", CostCredits = 1, CostType = "PerRequest"});

    SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Those are some interesting insights, thanks. What provider did you run against to get that error message? My original repro runs without exceptions.

Comment: @SergeySlepov InMemory as the repo shows. But the error comes from EF, not from the database. And the exception only comes when you explicit set `Service = ws3` for the `Endpoint` objects while having the `ws3.Endpoints = Endpoints.ToList();` line in it. This is indeed a weird behavior (or bug?) in EF, that the entity is not loaded when `Include()` is used. When you run a simple `context.Endpoints.ToList()` query you will get all `Endpoint` objects and using `Include()` shouldn't reduce this list.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation [discourages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#unit-testing) using the InMemory provider for any non-trivial database queries:

> we use the EF in-memory database when unit testing something that uses DbContext. In this case using the EF in-memory database is appropriate because the test is not dependent on database behavior. **Just don't do this to test actual database queries or updates.**

The InMemory provider won't run any joins for you which is what I was trying to do. The alternatives are using LocalDb or SqLite.

Comment: UPDATE 2: When I switch *back* to InMemory, the query still works. I have nothing but to admit that the problem was in AddSomeData().