# Adding a list parameter to an ASP.NET Core model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to add a list of string comments to my data model. After some googling this is what I came up with:

```
public class TaskItem
{
  public long Id { get; set; };
  public string title { get; set; };
  public List<Comment> comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public string comment_text { get; set; }
}
```

Sending a POST using Postman gives a nice 201 response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "First task",
  "comments": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "comment_text": "This is one comment"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "comment_text": "Here is another"
     }
   ]
}
```

BUT: using a GET request to retrieve the item yields "null" in the comments field (with response code 200):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "First task",
  "comments": null   <--------- ???
}
```

Why does the API not return the POST-ed comments?

Thanks in advance/David

EDIT: Per request, here is the relevant parts of my controller (auto-generated with Visual Studio):

```
 // GET: api/TaskItems/5
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
 public async Task<ActionResult<TaskItem>> GetTaskItem(long id)
 {
     var taskItem = await _context.TaskItems.FindAsync(id);

     if (taskItem == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     return taskItem
}

// POST: api/TaskItems
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TaskItem>> PostTaskItem(TaskItem taskItem)
{
    _context.TaskItems.Add(taskItem);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTaskItem), new { id = taskItem.Id }, taskItem);
}
```

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight ***exactly*** what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Comment: Why are you using a GET when a POST works?  A Get and Post both return responses.  The only difference is a Post the request has data in the body while a Get request the body is empty.

Comment: Can you show your controller pls?

Comment: @jdweng Uuuh first I want to add comments and then I want to retrieve all comments? Feels counter-intuitive to POST something to get a list of comments

Comment: @Nkosi To avoid a bloated question I picked the parts of the code that I thought were relevant. I've now also added the controller.

Comment: @Sergey See edit :)

Comment: @DavidMontgomery most likely the comments were not saved on POST and therefore not retrieved when making the subsequent GET request.

Comment: Isn't the issue just lazy loading ?  as you have a missing include after the `_context.TaskItems`?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/ . There should be a clear dupe somewhere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core returns null relations until direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access)

Comment: @DragandDrop Thank you you were right - lazy loading was what I was looking for! Will update with a proper answer

Comment: @DragandDrop Could you elaborate on what you meant by "as you have a missing include after the _context.TaskItems"? I read the article you linked but couldn't figure out what you meant by that part.

Comment: This linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access/42329028#42329028, show how to use `Include` to locally eager load a part you need. Without changing the context configuration. `_context.TaskItems.FindAsync(id).Include(x=> x.comments );` with the `using System.Data.Entity;`. Its "_Find the task and include the comments too_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @Drag and Drop I managed to figure this out - I had to use lazy loading. First I installed lazy loading proxies:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
```

I then updated my model to this:

```
public class TaskItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> comments { get; set; } // <-- This had to be virtual
}

public class Comment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string comment_text { get; set; }
}
```

I also had to change in my context:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddDbContext<TaskContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseLazyLoadingProxies() // <-- This I had to add
        .UseInMemoryDatabase("TaskData"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the  Comment class should have TaskItemId foreign key. You can't get the comments back after saving them without this foreign key:

```
public class Comment
{
  public long Id { get; set; }

  public long TaskItemId { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("TaskItemId")]
 public TaskItem TaskItem { get; set; }
  public string comment_text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Serget thanks for answering. I tried but couldn't get this to work. See my answer above for the solution that I could get to do the job