# When are navigation properties initialized on entities (EF Core 3.1)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, navigation-properties

I have a scenario where I'm inserting quite a few related entities into the database with lazy-loading disabled. In one case I initialize the entity and then insert it as so:

```cs
// SomeObj is an entity with an identity specification in its primary key column.
var obj = new SomeObj
{
    SomeTypeId = 1,
    SomeOtherTypeId = 185,
};

context.SomeObjs.Add(obj);
context.SaveChanges();
```

What I'm noticing is that in the context of my application when this happens `SomeOtherType` (the navigation property which `SomeOtherTypeId` is the foreign key of) is initialized while `SomeType` is not initialized.

Both navigation properties are defined using the FluentAPI in the same way:

```cs
entity.HasOne(d => d.SomeType)
    .WithMany(p => p.SomeObjs)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.SomeTypeId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_SomeObj_SomeType");

entity.HasOne(d => d.SomeOtherType)
    .WithMany(p => p.SomeObjs)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.SomeOtherTypeId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
    .HasConstraintName("FK_SomeObj_SomeOtherType");
```

I hopped into LINQPad to see if I could reproduce this half-initialization of navigation properties on insert and I could not. Inserting a single entity of `SomeObj` type in LINQPad resulted in NONE of the navigation properties being initialized (which seems more reasonable than half of them being initialized).

So this got me to wondering: when are navigation properties actually initialized in EF Core 3.1? As noted above, lazy-loading is disabled (which is why it is reasonable to me that all of the navigation properties are null).

I can work around this by following up the insert with:

```
obj = context.SomeObjs
    .Include(o => o.SomeType)
    .Include(o => o.SomeOtherType)
    .First(o => o.Id == obj.Id);
```

But this is only one small example in a larger code base and it seems more like there's something I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access/42329028#42329028. The key is a Tip in the documentation. If your `context` is empty new object, then both won't be populated. If one is populated, then most likely the related object is loaded in (tracked by) the context by some other code.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah, so if I'm understanding that correctly the specific context instance will only patch in those navigation properties for entities which were previously loaded. So if I were to do `context.SomeTypes.ToList();` and `context.SomeOtherTypes.ToList();` it would A) query all records of both tables and B) patch the navigation properties on `SaveChanges()`. In fact, I just tested this in LINQPad and that appears to be the case.

Comment: Actually not only previously. They can be patched later as well :) Anytime navigation fixup is performed. For instance, in your example, **after** `Add`, do `context.SomeType.Load();` and you'll see. This is what I tried to explain in the linked post - toy can force EFC to load them using any of the 3 methods, but you can't stop it to load them at any time (to keep them `null`) when tracked.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @IvanStoev. That makes perfect sense.