# Why did Entity Framework Core include related tables without me using Include() in my query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core version 5 and this is my table:

```cs
public class BusinessTransaction
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public bool IsPay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long Time { get; set; }
    public string TrackingCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BusinessId))]
    public Businesses.Business Business { get; set; } 
}
```

When I want to get data, EF Core seems to include the `Business` table without me using an `Include()`. This is my query:

```cs
public async Task<List<BusinessTransaction>> GetTransactionByBusienssId(Guid id, int skip = 0, int take = 10)
{
    var query = DbContext.BusinessTransactions
                         .Where(b => b.BusinessId == id)
                         .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
                         .Skip(skip)
                         .Take(take);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

This is query that executes in SQL Server (reformatted for readability):

```sql
DECLARE @__id_0 uniqueIdentifier = '2af03a2e-17b6-4708-ceee-08da1fc18b20';
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 10;
    
SELECT
    [b].[Id],
    [b].[Amount],
    [b].[BusinessId],
    [b].[Date],
    [b].[IsPay],
    [b].[Time],
    [b].[Title],
    [b].[TrackingCode]
FROM
    [BusinessTransactions] AS [b]
WHERE
    [b].[BusinessId] = @__id_0
ORDER BY
    [b].[Date] DESC
OFFSET
    @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY;
```

How can I execute query without including any related table?

Comment: Cn you show us the actual SQL query generated?

Comment: @user18387401 how can i show the query?

Comment: I believe that you should be able to remove the `ToListAsync` to get an unrealised query and call `ToQueryString` on that. You can then call `ToListAsync` on that same query to keep your code working the same way.

Comment: @user18387401 this my query:                                                                             
DECLARE @__id_0 uniqueIdentifier = '2af03a2e-17b6-4708-ceee-08da1fc18b20';
DECLARE @__p_1 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 10;

SELECT [b].[Id], [b].[Amount], [b].[BusinessId], [b].[Date], [b].[IsPay], [b].[Time], [b].[Title], [b].[TrackingCode]
FROM [BusinessTransactions] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[BusinessId] = @__id_0
ORDER BY [b].[Date] DESC
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_2 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Please update the question, formatting the code appropriately.

Comment: @user18387401 i update the question

Comment: _"now how can i execute query without Includes related table?"_ - Neither your Linq query nor the generated T-SQL query includes other entities or tables, so why are you asking this question?

Comment: @Dai i am not opposed. my question is how i didnt use include and entity framework loaded related table. it is unnecessary data and decrease perfomance

Comment: @rezaashouri I've reworded your question for you.

Comment: @rezaashouri EF isn't loading additional data _in that method_ - any other entities you're seeing being loaded will be from earlier queries executed against the same `DbContext` instance. (That said, you haven't actually told us what additional data you're seeing being loaded, and do you have `LazyLoading` enabled or disabled?)

Comment: The SQL generated by EF Core **isn't** "including" any other entity other than `BusinessTransactions` - the entity which you actually wrote your Linq query against. I don't understand what you think is being "included" additionally - nothing is ...

Comment: @Dai aha thank you i understand that but i have question how to prevent that  additional data doesnt load into the object?

Comment: @marc_s Business object is loaded into BusinessTransactions object

Comment: @rezaashouri That `Business` object is being loaded elsewhere (you'll need to show **all** your code that uses that `DbContext`) - or it's being loaded inadvetently via a Navigation Property accessor due to `LazyLoading == true`.

Comment: *"Business object is loaded into BusinessTransactions object"*. No it isn't. EF is only getting the data you're asking for, which is those specific `BusinessTransaction` objects. If you try to access the `Business` object related to one of them then EF will go and get it then. It's not there until you ask for it. If you don't want it retrieved, don't ask for it.

Comment: @rezaashouri Set a breakpoint on the `BusinessTransaction.Business` property setter (click on `set;` and press F9) then run your program. The debugger will show when the `Business` property is being set.

Comment: @Dai no i dont use lazyload. The Bussiness object that loaded into BusinessTransactions i get that with the same instance of DbContext in previous line codes

Comment: @user18387401 "any other entities you're seeing being loaded will be from earlier queries executed against the same DbContext instance" earlier query i get Bussiness Object with the same DbContext instance and i think its automapping into BusinessTransaction

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access/42329028#42329028 you can find some explanation of the behavior with links to documentation. The only way to prevent it is using no tracking queries (e,g, `AsNoTracking` etc.)

Comment: You dont want to send full object to client or your performance is slow cause of nested objects? Cause in first case you can use DataTransferObjects (dtos) and map original object to dto which doesnt include some of original object's properties

Answer (score -2):

Your question is related to Eager loading, Please read below concepts of eager vs lazy. When you call include() it is eager loading where EF calls all related entities, I believe what you look for is lazy loading where EF won't load related entities (navigation props) until you explicitly call them.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Good luck.